# How do I convert a string to a dictionary, where each entry to the dictionary is assigned a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I convert a string to a dictionary, where each entry to the dictionary is assigned a value?

At the minute, I have this code:

```
text = "Here's the thing. She doesn't have anything to prove, but she is going to anyway. That's just her character. She knows she doesn't have to, but she still will just to show you that she can. Doubt her more and she'll prove she can again. We all already know this and you will too."

d = {}
lst = []

def findDupeWords():
    string = text.lower()  

    #Split the string into words using built-in function  
    words = string.split(" ")  

    print("Duplicate words in a given string : ")  
    for i in range(0, len(words)):  
        count = 1  
        for j in range(i+1, len(words)):  
            if(words[i] == (words[j])):  
                count = count + 1  
                #Set words[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited word  
                words[j] = "0"  

        #Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
        if(count > 1 and words[i] != "0"):  
            print(words[i])

for key in d:
    text = text.replace(key,d[key])

print(text)
findDupeWords()
```

The output I get when I run this is:

```
Here's the thing. She doesn't have anything to prove, but she is going to anyway. That's just her character. She knows she doesn't have to, but she still will just to show you that she can. Doubt her more and she'll 
prove she can again. We all already know this and you will too.
Duplicate words in a given string : 
she
doesn't
have
to
but
just
her
will
you
and
```

How can I turn this list of words into a dictionary, like the following:
`{'she': 1, 'doesn't': 2, 'have': 3, 'to': 4}` , etc...

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use an instance of a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the standard library.

```
from collections import Counter

def findDupeWords(text):
    counter = Counter(text.lower().split(" "))
    for word in counter:
        if counter[word] > 1:
            print(word)

text = "Here's the thing. She doesn't have anything to prove, but she is going to anyway. That's just her character. She knows she doesn't have to, but she still will just to show you that she can. Doubt her more and she'll prove she can again. We all already know this and you will too."
findDupeWords(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could replace your call to `print` with an assignment to a dictionary:

```
def findDupeWords():
    duplicates = {}
    duplicate_counter = 0
    ...
        #Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
        if(count > 1 and words[i] != "0"):  
            duplicate_counter += 1
            duplicates[words[i]] = duplicate_counter
```

But there are easier ways to achieve this, for example with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

words = text.lower().split()
word_occurrences = Counter(words)
dupes_in_order = sorted(
    (word for word in set(words) if word_occurrences[word] > 1),
    key=lambda w: words.index(w),
)
dupe_dictionary = {word: i+1 for i, word in enumerate(dupes_in_order)}
```

Afterwards:

```
>>> dupe_dictionary
{'she': 1,
 "doesn't": 2,
 'have': 3,
 'to': 4,
 'but': 5,
 'just': 6,
 'her': 7,
 'will': 8,
 'you': 9,
 'and': 10}
```

Comment: if I try to use the variable `duplicates` outside of the function, it says it isn't defined. How can i use it outside of the function?

Comment: how do i use this to replace the words with the number from the dictionary, becuase wouldn't they need to be the other way round?

Comment: In order to use this outside the function, use the `return` keyword to save the dictionary in a variable.  I was mistaken regarding the order of keys and values, I've edited my answer accordingly